# How does one detect the current cursor position of a Windows form textbox?

Tags: winforms, textbox

I'm trying to build a simple HTML text editor in a Windows Form application.  I would like to be able to programmatically detect where the text cursor is at a particular moment so I can insert text programmatically at that point.

I would have thought this was an obvious thing, like a property that gets or sets the current text cursor position, but I haven't found one!  So how do I find out where that cursor is?

Comment: How are you doing the HTML Editor? http://winformhtmltextbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've tried that HTML Editor, and it works well, but I wanted to roll my own -- the winformhtmltextbox has nice features, but I wanted a few things that it didn't provide.

Comment: really, interesting hopefully you share the goodness of your own project on codeplex. One thing lacking with the winformhtmltextbox is `SelectionStart` :P

Comment: Good idea!  If the result of my labor seems to be substantial enough I just might do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TextBox.SelectionStart` property.  The caret index starts at 0 for the left-most position.

Comment: Thanks!  I had briefly considered that property but its name suggested to me that it only applied if text was actually selected, so I disregarded it.  And the description in MSDN is very incomplete (as usual).